# Linq to SQL select one of every different result

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql

Let's say I have a table with two columns, name and template. Let's say i have multiple rows with the name foo and multiple rows with the name bar. All of them have template 3.

How do i perform a linq to SQL select that returns only one of each name with template number 3.

```
(from f in g_lisFilters where f.Template == "3" orderby f.Sortering select f).ToList();
```

above code returns a list of all items with template number 3. How do i select only one of every name?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply have to group the data by template, and take the first element of each group.

```
  var firsts = from e in g_lisFilters 
          where f.Template == "3"
          group by e.Sortering 
              into groups
              select groups.First();
```

Or

```
var firsts = g_lisFilters
     .Where(e.Template="3")
     .GroupBy(e=>e.Sortering ,(key,g)=>g.First());
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the 'Distinct' method? It ignores multiple results of the same.

Maybe this could help you: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348436(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Distinct won't work because the items selected are not exactly the same, they also have own guid's etcetera but are matched on name further in the code. Thanks for the input tho